# VLCJ-4: audio playback stops too early ("finished" event is fired before end of media)

Tags: java, events, migration, vlc, vlcj

After migrating my Java application from `vlcj-3.12.1` to `vlcj-4.8.2` I am observing that the `finished()` event is being fired approximately 2 seconds before the media has reached its end/full length/duration. This messes up my GUI as I have a media time display showing both elapsed and remaining time. So when it shows 2 seconds remaining now, it suddenly jumps down to 0 and it sounds like the last bit of the audio is being "cut off".

I have tried various media files and various audio formats with different bitrates (including VBR) - the result is identical in all cases. The following [logfile snipplet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCFRk.png%3E) shows that the length of the media is being correctly read when the `playing()` event is received (**24 secs**). I am logging the `timeChanged()` events during playback. You can see that these events stop coming right before the media time reaches **~22 secs**. Then the `finished()` event gets fired. No more `timeChanged()` events thereafter - the last 2 seconds of playback are missing.

Is this a bug in `VLC` or `VLCJ` which is targeted for an upcoming version or might I be doing something wrong? The issue did not occur with `vlcj-3.12.1` and it also does not occur when playing the media with native VLC. I really don't want to downgrade again but this is kind of a let-down. I am running the latest `VLC` version `3.0.17.4` on Windows 10 with `Java 17.0.5`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not using my own timer, I'm doing it exactly the way you described it. I am listening to vlcj's time-changed events and whenever there is one, I am calling the getMediaTime() method on the vlcj media player. The media time that is returned is then passed to the time display

Comment: You are right there, but as you said, it's not the issue. vlcj gives me the length of the media. The elapsed time is the time that comes with the time-changed event, the remaining time is the length of the media minus the current media time. The log shows that vlcj tells me the media duration is 24 seconds, but it sends the finished event after 22 seconds. Which causes the problem. It should be easy to reproduce

Comment: I also observed that VLC now sends a stopped event after finished (which was not the case earlier), but the stopped event is fired only a few milliseconds after the finished event. So that's also not where the 2 seconds did go...

Comment: It's hard to extract the code and post it here, as it is distributed among several classes and quite complex. I'll try what I can do, but it'll take time...

Comment: That's interesting. I've always ignored those events as I didn't understand what they are useful for. I logged them now, but it doesn't make a difference:
Initial length after the playing event: 24171.
Length after the first lenghth-changed event: 24172.
Length after the last lenghth-changed event: 24171.
Media time of last time-changed event: 22112.
Then the finished event is fired.
I really don't understand what's going on there. I downloaded your vlcj sample application and I don't see the issue there, playing the same file. So far I could not figure out major differences in our codes

Comment: I have found the issue. It is due to the following VLC parameters that I have passed to the MediaPlayerFactory: [--file-caching=2000 --network-caching=2000]. It's exactly these 2 seconds the player stops earlier. I've been using these settings for years and it never was a problem in previous versions of VLC. I always thought that caching would prevent the player from possible "stuttering" when playing larger files (audio or video) from a network drive, but obviously it has some weird side effects now. Maybe it's a bug. I have removed caching for now and everything is back to normal

Comment: Interesting, never knew it worked like that. You could write your own answer and accept it, you never know it might help someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. The issue was related to the following VLC parameters that I passed to the MediaPlayerFactory:

```
--file-caching=2000
--network-caching=2000
```

It is exactly these 2 seconds that the media player skips playing at the end of the file. Not sure how this is related, maybe it's a bug. These settings haven't caused any trouble in previuos versions of VLC. I have removed caching for now and everything is back to normal.